# Backbone: How to get model attributes from a collection inside another model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

Model code:

```
App.Team = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
urlRoot: 'data/json/team',
/*urlRoot: 'data/json/myteam.txt',*/
idAttribute: 'id',
relations:
...

app.currentTeam = new App.Team({id:11});
```

View:

```
var trophiesBox = JST['teaminfo/history/leftbox'](app.currentTeam.attributes);
    $("#teamhistory_leftbox").append(trophiesBox);  
    for (var i = 1; i <= app.currentTeam.attributes.history.length; i++)   { 
        var historyData = app.currentTeam.attributes.history.get(i);
        var historyRow = JST['teaminfo/history/row']    (historyData.attributes);
        $("#teamhistory_table_body").append(historyRow);
    }
```

I'm getting `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined"`
on `var historyRow = JST['teaminfo/history/row']    (historyData.attributes);` line.

Before I had problems defining historyData, probably since it is a model in a collection (`app.currentTeam.attributes.history`) inside of another model (`app.currentTeam`). I was getting `[Object] (app.currentTeam.attributes.history) doesn't have a 'get' method` type of error. Now it passes fine, but I get another error message in the next line, so I wonder what is wrong with my code here.

`app.currentTeam.attributes` loads fine, so I guess there is a problem retrieving attributes of a model that is inside a collection within another model.

**Edit:** relation of Team and History collection:

```
{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'history',
    relatedModel: 'App.HistoryItem',
    collectionType: 'App.History',
    reverseRelation: {
        key: 'team',
        includeInJSON: 'id',
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show relation of Team and History Collection

Comment: @Sergey I added the relation.

Comment: Why you use attributes.history instead get('history')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get Model from Collection from wrong method

```
app.currentTeam.attributes.history.get(i);
```

You have to use

```
app.currentTeam.get('history') // you got collection
app.currentTeam.get('history').at(i); // you got model from collection by index
```

Update1:
Try use iterator for get elements from collection:

```
var trophiesBox = JST['teaminfo/history/leftbox'](app.currentTeam.attributes);
$("#teamhistory_leftbox").append(trophiesBox);  
app.currentTeam.get('history').each(function(historyData, i) {
    var historyRow = JST['teaminfo/history/row'](historyData.attributes);
    $("#teamhistory_table_body").append(historyRow);
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code, but I still get the same error. I wonder what else can cause it.

Comment: Do you debug your app in javascript's debuggers? Chrome Development Tools or FireBug?

Comment: The code now is: 
var historyData = app.currentTeam.get('history').at(i);

Comment: And set breakpoint on this line and show waht stored on app.currentTeam.get('history')

Comment: When it stops, it shows: historyData: undefined, but when I press "Continue" it starts loading every model one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/speed.html). This might be of some help.